# Send AJAX request to url: button.click()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm writing a little bot for a page and I need to click on a button. But that button would link me to another page so that I'd had to reenter my script to the browser's console. That's why I want to send an ajax request and set `$("body")` to its result.

The problem is, I don't know where the button links to and it's not as simple as `$("#btn").prop("href")`. It's a `<button>` tag. Of course I tried to find out what happens when the button is clicked so I can do the same, but it turned out that this is very difficult.

Can I do something like `$.ajax({ url: $("#btn").click() })` ?
Or do you know a way to simply debug what exactly gets triggered when clicking on that button?

```
<div id="checkoutNextbottom" class="checkoutNext"> 
   <button name="buttonNext" id="nextbottom" class="linkAsButton processButtonNext">Weiter</button> 
   <!----> 
</div>
```

Comment: show the according html

Comment: <div id="checkoutNextbottom" class="checkoutNext">
  <button name="buttonNext" id="nextbottom" class="linkAsButton processButtonNext">Weiter</button>
  <!---->
</div>

Comment: use a regular `<a>` tag, and instead just give it a class of a button, this way it will look and act like a button but will still be a regular link

Answer (score 0):

try like this ...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#nextbottom").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({type: "method type",
            url: "url",
            data: data,
            success:function(result){

            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: this is not what i want. i do not even know where to link, because i don't know what happens everything when clicked on that button

Comment: can you make clear what you want exactly else if you have code with you add here i will check ..